# date.prototype.tojson override in typescript not using the correct context

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having an issue formatting date as json using a callback function.
I have a call called Event with a date property dateTimeOfEvent that I want to format as ISO date format.

this works great:

```
event.dateTimeOfEvent.toJSON = function() {
  const isoDate: string = moment(this).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  return isoDate;
};
```

but I want to create a reusable callback function, I couldn't make the following code work:

```
private  dateToJsonString(date: any): string {
  const isoDate: string = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  return isoDate;
}
event.dateTimeOfEvent.toJSON = this.dateToJsonString;
```

dateToJsonString seems to get the string 'dateTimeOfEvent' as a parameter and not the actual date value.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by by it did not work? any error and what output you get?

Comment: i mean that the dateToJsonString function got a string ''dateTimeOfEvent" as parameter and not the actual date value it needs to format

Comment: Can you try - event.dateTimeOfEvent.toJSON = dateToJsonString.bind(dateTimeOfEvent);

Comment: event.dateTimeOfEvent.toJSON = this.dateToJsonString.bind(dateTimeOfEvent); ?

the compiler doesn't recognize dateTimeOfEvent that way